# VSCode can't load project Java library - how to fix?

Tags: java, kotlin, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get VSCode to work properly a Java/Kotlin project, but when I click on 'Java Dependencies', it lists nothing, and the Language Support for Java console shows an exception:

```
[Error - 3:18:00 PM] Jul 3, 2019 3:18:00 PM Problem load project library 
yourLibrary does not exist
Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [yourLibrary does not exist]
```

The project works fine when built with Gradle, and runs with no problem as well. My company uses some customized build tools, environment settings (including what I think is a fork of Gradle 5.3.1), so maybe this isn't going to be feasible. Note that we *are* able to get Intellij to work properly, so I'm hopeful VSCode may work as well, but have no idea what steps to take to debug. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yep! I had the jars in a different folder; not sure if there is a way to tell code to "look in myLibFolder/", but renaming worked at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding external Jar files whithout maven or gradle .classpath file must be changed for the library.

1.create a folder named `lib` inside your project and add your `.jar` file into it

2.Configure paths in the `.classpath` like:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/xxxx.jar"/>
```

3.if it still thow error,Clean the workspace directory:`F1` - input `Clean` -`clean workspace`